# Netellet API error: invalid_scope

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I'm trying to get the user's permission for three scopes (`subscription_payment`, `account_enhanced_profile` and `account_available_balance`), and I'm trying this, to get them:

```
https://test.api.neteller.com/v1/oauth2/authorize?client_id=################&redirect_uri=https://paymentstest/gateways/neteller/confirmpayment.php&scope=subscription_payment+account_enhanced_profile+account_available_balance&response_type=code
```

In the API, they have this documented, in the scopes section:

> The supplied scope parameter will indicate the level of access you require for your app. The scope parameter MUST be supplied. If you application requires multiple scopes then you should supply a space separated list of the required permissions. Eg. `scope=perm1+perm2`

but I still get this error, when I perform the request:

```
{ 
    ["error"] => "invalid_scope" 
    ["error_description"] => "The requested scope is invalid, unknown, or malformed." 
}
```

Why could I be getting this error? I am using php, and `urlencode()` to add the scopes to the link. This is a redirect to call the 'client' for their permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in the documentation. The correct way to pass multiple scopes is to list them separated by a comma, like so:

```
https://test.api.neteller.com/v1/oauth2/authorize?client_id=################&redirect_uri=https://paymentstest/gateways/neteller/confirmpayment.php&scope=subscription_payment,account_enhanced_profile,account_available_balance&response_type=code
```

Comment: Thank you! I got it right once, but I didn't know how, and I thought it was with the '+' sign... so I was getting crazy!